# problem with cropping and alignment

Tags: crop

I'm trying to make a layout suitable for two-side printing and cutting. I used geometry package with these parameters:

```
a4paper,
paperwidth=210mm,
paperheight=297mm,
bindingoffset=1cm,
layoutwidth=178mm,
layoutheight=235.5mm,
layouthoffset=0mm,
layoutvoffset=0mm,
includeheadfoot,
ignoremp,
textwidth=148mm,%180mm,
textheight=215.5mm,%257mm,
top=0.5cm,
bottom=0.5cm,
inner=2cm,
outer=1cm,
showcrop
```

How can I align the page content to different sides (or both in the middle) so I can cut the paper after printing. Here's an example of the result.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`geometry` is not able to switch the position in odd and even pages, so the best is to center and to crop on both sides. Since you're giving explicitly the dimensions, just copy them and tell TeX to do the computation:

```
layouthoffset=\dimexpr(210mm-178mm)/2\relax,
```

You can also use parameters:

```
layouthoffset=\dimexpr(\paperwidth-\csname Gm@layoutwidth\endcsname)/2\relax,
```

provided, of course, that you announced paper format and `layoutwidth` in advance.